# TypeError - Parameter must be a string While Parsing a URL

Tags: node.js

I have two questions.

I have a code snippet below

```
var http = require('http'),      
    https = require('https'),
    crypto = require('crypto');
var S = require('string');
var url = require('url');
var req = require('request');

var path = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
```

The error message points at

```
var path = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
```

saying throw new TypeError("Parameter  'url' must be a string.  not " + typeof url)

What is wrong with that statemet?  Do I have to put that statement in a function?  But, I do not know what function I should create for dong url parsing.

My second question refers to the code snippet below.  Can I compare the path that I extract from a URL and compare it with a string using **==**   ?

```
if ((S(path) == '/lens/v1/ping') || (S(path) == '/lens/v1/PING')) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.write('The lens route is up and running!\n');
    res.end();
} else {
    res.writeHead(404, 'Not Found');
    res.end('HTTP 1.1 404/Not Found');
}
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: As for your first question, it's better to share your goal, because you organize your code in a wrong way: `req` cannot be used as an object. Please, read a little bit more about callbacks also.

Answer (score 1):

If req is request module, then url does not exist in req. So you must get error.

**You need to parse the URL inside of your routing function, where the req variable lives.**

**See below example:**

**Example 1:**

```
app.get("/page", function(req, res) {
  var uri = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
}
```

**Example 2:**

```
http.createServer(function(req, res){
  var uri = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`var req = require('request')`

https://github.com/mikeal/request/blob/master/request.js

req is a function...

And yes, if you have a request **object**, then path would be a string and you can use `==` or `===`.

Comment: I still cannot get it right.  I have tried **var path = req.url.pathname;** and I got another TypeError: Cannot read property 'pathname' of undefined.  I checked the URL module.  It seems that I should do **var path = url.parse(req).pathname;** but, it does not work either.

Comment: Just read: req is a FUNCTION. I don't know what you try to achieve but you're doing it wrong. I suggest you, without any nastiness, to drop NodeJS and begin with simple Javascript.